# using rails geocoder when object has 2 sets of coordinates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.3

So I have two models, both have two sets of coordinates.

The first model, `Load`, has `from_lat/lng`, as well as `to_lat/lng`.
The second model, Trucks, has `current_lat/lng` as well as `destination_lat/lng`.

What I'm trying to do is find all the results that have either the `current_lat/lng` or `destination_lat/lng` from the Truck model near the to_lat/lng of the Load model.

My model for lanes is something like:

```
class Load < ActiveRecord::Base  

  has_many :trucks

  geocoded_by :custom_geocode  

  after_validation :custom_geocode

  def custom_geocode  
    var = Geocoder.coordinates([from_city,from_state].compact.join(','))  
    var2 = Geocoder.coordinates([to_city,to_state].compact.join(','))  
    self.from_lat = var.first  
    self.from_lng = var.last  
    self.to_lat = var2.first  
    self.to_lng = var2.last  
  end
end
```

In my view, I have:

```
<% for truck in @trucks %>  
  <li><%= truck.destination_lat %></li>  
<% end %>
```

Currently I am using this in my loads_controller:

```
def show
  @load = Load.find(params[:id])
  @trucks = Truck.near([@load.from_lat, @load.from_lng], 100, :order => "distance")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @load }
  end
end
```

The error I get is:
`PG::Error: ERROR:  column trucks.latitude does not exist`

I know this is because the name of the columns are not the default `:latitude` and `:longitude`. How can I specify, during this specific search, which set of columns to use (destination_lat/lng or current_lat/lng) from the Truck model?

Comment: Did you find out? How did you solved it?

Comment: Any updates on this? I can't figure it out.

Comment: My suggestion to you would be to create a model who's sole job is just to house coordinates call load_coordinates. You could do some single table inheritance so that there are two type of these coordinate models (from_load_coordinates,  and to_load_coordinates). Then you could create a has_one relationship with both types of the coordinate models, then run your query on load_coordinates so that you get back hits on both sub types.